# Size of float and double

Tags: c++

Calculating the dot-product of two vectors (float value) gives the different results on the different machines:

```
6.102435302 (Win7 x64, compiler VS12 version 17.00.50727.1)
6.140244007 (Win7 x64, MinGW, gcc version 5.3.0)
```

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm> 

int main(int argc, char** argv){

std::ifstream is("test.txt");
std::istream_iterator<float> start(is), end;
std::vector<float> numbers(start, end);
std::cout << "Read " << numbers.size() << " numbers" << std::endl;

float product = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= numbers.size() - 1; i++)
    product += (numbers[i])*(numbers[i]); // += means add to product
std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << product << std::endl;

std::cin.get();
}
```

test.txt is:

```
-0.082833 
0.151422 
-0.088526 
-0.538506 
0.646273 
0.266993 
0.200206 
-0.149989 
0.141407 
0.158835 
-0.119255 
-0.039122 
-0.045419 
0.141848 
-0.218912 
-0.264521 
0.032238 
-0.055877 
0.100393 
-0.097075 
-0.006268 
-0.070172 
-0.275793 
0.103654 
-0.075405 
-0.117017 
0.029951 
-0.094158 
-0.168427 
0.381314 
0.144073 
-0.100971 
-0.078645 
0.013768 
0.144876 
0.005855 
-0.018223 
-0.090576 
-0.071564 
-0.029456 
-0.098014 
-0.149181 
0.200667 
-0.189492 
0.264529 
-0.061738 
-0.097826 
0.138872 
-0.241878 
0.019428 
-0.087634 
-0.058300 
-0.009269 
0.039241 
-0.066350 
0.059845 
-0.048516 
-0.070653 
-0.116227 
0.037203 
-0.037091 
-0.097324 
0.043834 
-0.340037 
0.133938 
0.087197 
0.213261 
-0.170708 
-0.151203 
0.052959 
0.027145 
-0.142675 
-0.209020 
0.001813 
-0.022321 
0.190862 
-0.015501 
-0.228589 
-0.038538 
-0.038480 
-0.194482 
0.087518 
-0.257362 
0.160805 
-0.114158 
0.176832 
0.219573 
-0.333160 
-0.068385 
-0.143289 
-0.228401 
0.214679 
0.277186 
-0.130965 
0.142526 
-0.166073 
-0.035309 
0.001260 
-0.064977 
0.020747 
0.014043 
-0.133625 
-0.156975 
-0.043092 
0.154749 
-0.181473 
-0.288339 
-0.144132 
-0.004081 
-0.071694 
-0.094631 
0.483994 
-0.260140 
0.020749 
0.031850 
0.041064 
0.250101 
-0.192338 
-0.222687 
0.114226 
-0.227428 
0.005388 
-0.163509 
-0.135427 
-0.206788 
-0.021093 
0.279840 
-0.055362 
-0.016305 
-0.279524 
0.277402 
0.198076 
0.103796 
-0.272994 
0.306518 
-0.024435 
0.149532 
-0.165079 
-0.394348 
-0.141590 
-0.188541 
0.002890 
0.064264 
-0.045430 
-0.026021 
0.096325 
0.033765 
0.111890 
-0.012204 
0.130457 
-0.106022 
-0.180052 
-0.447620 
0.051825 
0.089245 
-0.265819 
-0.087720 
0.180074 
-0.259521 
-0.356145 
0.162247 
0.282323 
-0.096935 
-0.040101 
-0.214359 
0.357032 
0.195393 
0.150603 
-0.120796 
0.204032 
0.130334 
0.115753 
-0.123727 
-0.107526 
0.196002 
-0.397541 
0.320854 
0.013272 
-0.058865 
0.018108 
0.023616 
-0.053654 
-0.223593 
-0.310052 
0.109229 
-0.107124 
0.074454 
-0.021471 
-0.033081 
0.108072 
-0.067013 
-0.084968 
-0.171947 
0.308421 
-0.204827 
-0.060015 
0.092264 
0.115863 
0.131043 
0.041844
```

I suppose, it somehow depends on the size of float and double and they are not the same for these machines. Is it possible to make the same output for both computers?

I have no access to the first machine (with the first result 6.102435302), but I can reproduce the same result with the following python code (with numpy):

```
test = np.loadtxt(test_file, dtype=np.float32)
result = test.dot(test)
```

Comment: can you post your code, your input and compiler settings?

Comment: And where is your [mcve]?

Comment: Normally, floating point accuracy in the last few bits cannot be guaranteed with various compiler optimization settings at default, however your values are _so far_ apart I can't think that this is the issue. Post your code.

Comment: Regarding the MCVE example that Barry requests, maybe you could add some information such as sizeof(double) and sizeof(float).

Comment: Sorry, my fault. This is a code that calculates the dot-product.

Comment: I get `6.140244007` with clang - I suspect there's a problem with your first compiler/machine/environment.

Comment: @PaulR,
thank you for testing. And why I get the first result with python either? Maybe you have an idea? (see the code above)

Comment: With python I get `6.140244007` also - are you *sure* your test.txt data file is identical on both systems ?

Comment: can you try to hard-code the values instead of reading them from file? Just to be sure that the error doesn't come from reading-in!

Comment: I get 6.140244007 on VS 2012 as well as VS2015 but don't have the same compiler release.

Comment: @PaulR,
yes, i am sure, it is the same file. What python version do you have? 2.7.11?

Comment: @KTBFFH: 2.7.10 (on Mac OS X), FWIW. I expect you've identified the problem by now though - I'm guessing [Mike Vine's hypothesis](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36406930/253056) was correct ?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is too large to be explained by using float instead of double. Look for actual bugs in your code. Or your calculation is *highly* unstable, in which case you really need to examine what's going on and can't trust any numbers until you understood what's going on.

Getting the same output for both compilers is easy - just set the result to zero. But what you want is to get the *correct* result. You have one result that is badly wrong, and one that cannot be trusted, and you don't know which one is which. Making the results the same would only cover this up but not solve any problem.

Comment: Most likely this is the result of large product terms that are very close in magnitude but opposite in polarity. When combined, the relative error increases. This is often also seen with ill conditioned matrixes.

Comment: @doug: the terms are all squared though, so all positive.

Comment: Ah, thanks for including the code and data.  This is fairly common. When you add a long list of number to an accumulator the initial data is added more accurately than the data at the end because the accumulator becomes much larger in magnitude. Think of adding 1.333333 and .0000333333. When data is read in and not rounded to the exact machine precision but truncated you can get a bias that adds up faster.  When accumulating operations on vectors of floats I always use a double.

Comment: Looking at this some more I believe it's probably due to reading in the data values with some significant error in the last place. Might be useful to run the program reading in the data floats and doubles and see where they significantly differ.

Answer (score 3):

It looks likely that the VS12 auto vectorized the loop (and then you mis-typed the result).

If you run the loop vectorised as so:

```
float product = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i+= 4)
{
    __m128 val = *(__m128*)(&numbers[i]);
    auto res = _mm_dp_ps (val, val, 255);
    float result;
    _mm_store_ss(&result, res);

    product += result;
}
```

Then the result you get out is:

6.14024353

This is the same as your first result of `6.102435302` but it looks like you missed the `4` out whilst transcribing.

At least the the best explanation I can come up with. Already spent way too long on this question :-)

Comment: Very nice detective work leading to plausible hypothesis!